# Resize the radius with in ChartJs Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

[image]

I.m using ChartJs for "doughnut-pie-chart". The default radius is much bigger than what I expect,. Is there and way to resize the radius width.?

The documentatin part did not provide any info.

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-area").getContext("2d");

    new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(doughnutData, {responsive : true});
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Extend the Doughnut chart to set the outerRadius (perhaps using an option that you pass in) after the prototype's initialization

```
Chart.types.Doughnut.extend({
    name: "DoughnutAlt",
    initialize: function(data){
        Chart.types.Doughnut.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
        this.outerRadius *= this.options.radiusPercentage;
    }
});
```

and then use the extended chart type

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-area").getContext("2d");
var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).DoughnutAlt(doughnutData, {
    responsive : true,
    radiusPercentage: 0.8
});
```